# How to protect users from malware utilizing protocols such as DNS over HTTPS?

Tags: encryption, tls, malware, dns

With the increased drive to enable DNS over HTTPS (DoH), it's likely that non-browser applications and systems may utilize DoH services other than those promoted by Mozilla and Google.

Since malware authors will leverage these capabilities, are there effective ways to protect users and devices? If yes, what would be examples of these?

Comment: It is not clear from the question how the use of DoH by the malware creates a new problem. If you could elaborate on what new problems get created by the use of DoH instead of normal DNS one could address these specific points. Currently there is only your broad claim that it somehow will be a problem but without any details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Please see https://www.zdnet.com/article/first-ever-malware-strain-spotted-abusing-new-doh-dns-over-https-protocol/ and issues it presents.

Comment: I cannot see anything in the post you refer to which shows that DoH is a new kind of problem which need to be addressed. Yes, it is using DoH instead of plain DNS to get C2 information. But other malware is getting this information from twitter posts, comments on blog etc so DoH is not special in that it gets this information via encryption (and also using HTTPS) from some remote site. If you feel different then please include the relevant details in your question instead of just referring to some external source and expect others to figure out what you mean.

Comment: malware didn't wait for DoH to exist in order to use DNS as a cover channel for communication, in both directions.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - To clarify, do you mean to say that DoH is not a issue in introducing increased complexity in malware detection, prevention and response? If yes, why do you believe it's not an issue? DNS in my understanding (albeit limited at the moment and hence the question), is a significant control in mitigating malware. If this as I comprehend it becomes challenging to manage, won't it become an issue?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - I'm not suggesting malware did not exist prior to DoH. Unless I am missing something obvious, DoH undermines another control in responding to such threats. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: @Motivated: I'm not saying that DoH is not an issue but it is not as much as in issue that it needs the special handling you ask for. This is just another channel on how to use  seemingly innocent communication via HTTPS to commonly visited servers for C2 purposes. Focusing too much on DoH instead on the more general problem misses the point.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Does it not reduce the ability to detect considerably when attempts are made to communicate with domains that stage payloads? Maybe I'm missing something in my understanding. DNS in my view has always been a critical control point. DoH seems to dilute this. Happy to be corrected.

Comment: @Motivated security wise, what is the difference between a malware using DOH towards a known public resolver from a malware using a custom protocol over HTTPS to any server out there?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - The ability to inspect the DNS request. I am assuming (again, happy to be corrected) that a custom protocol over HTTPS doesn't necessarily remove the need to resolve. It's either DNS or IP address.

Comment: @Motivated: I've already said that the same kind of information retrieval as done with DNS and DoH (get the C2 server, get payloads) is already done with other methods (twitter feed, comments on blogs, ...). So DoH just adds yet another similar thing but does not add a new quality. Sure, if the existing detection and protection was based solely on plain DNS then DoH bypasses this. But in this case the previous detection was already too limited to deal with real-world attacks and C2.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - If I have understood you correctly, do you mean so say that DoH doesn't increase the risk?

Comment: @Motivated: I'm saying that DoH does not add a new quality to the risk. Focusing too much on DoH instead of the more general risk of hidden C2 employing HTTPS with trusted domains misses the point.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Is there an option to take this to chat? I'm keen to understand your feedback on trusted domains further.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the non-DNS traffic, as you should be doing anyway. Remember, malware can use raw IP addresses just as easily as it can use DNS-over-HTTPS.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "non-DNS" traffic? How would these be monitored if it's we interleaved with web traffic on port 443?

Comment: @Motivated You're missing my point. My point is that malware can evade your DNS snooping by just not using DNS period.

Comment: I understand. My question still stands to reason as to how these can be monitored if the traffic is tunneled via "approved" channels?

Comment: @Motivated Now you're basically asking "how can I defend against malware that communicates over HTTPS", which is no longer DNS-related.

Comment: -Since DNS is leveraging HTTPS, yes that is a valid comment and hence my question on the ability to identify malware that may have utilized DNS before e.g. DGA however matures to using DoH.